# Buffer.BlockCopyについて

Tags: c#, .net

```
    int CD_SIZE  = 2;   
    int USE_SIZE = 3;
    int COUNT_SIZE = 1; 
    int UNKNOWN_SIZE = 5;           // 5B謎サイズ
    int LENGTH_SIZE = 1;
    int FOOTER_SIZE = 1;

    int nowPos  = 0;                            
    byte[] Count    = new byte[COUNT_SIZE];
    byte[] Length   = new byte[LENGTH_SIZE];

    nowPos += CD_SIZE + USE_SIZE;


    Buffer.BlockCopy( byteData, nowPos, Count, 0, COUNT_SIZE );
    int CountSize = Convert.ToInt32( BytesConvert.ToHexString( Count ), 16 );

    nowPos += COUNT_SIZE;
        for( int i = 0; i < CountSize; i++ ) {
            nowPos += UNKNOWN_SIZE;
            Buffer.BlockCopy( byteData, nowPos, Length, 0, LENGTH_SIZE );
            int strSize = Convert.ToInt32( BytesConvert.ToHexString( Length ), 16 );
            nowPos += LENGTH_SIZE;
            byte[] ResultByte = new byte[strSize];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(byteData, nowPos, ResultByte, 0, strSize) 
            nowPos += strSize + FOOTER_SIZE;
        }
}
```

Buffer.BlockCopyの部分で
配列のオフセットおよび長さが範囲を超えているか、カウンタがソース コレクションのインデックスから最後までの要素の数より大きい値です。
とエラーがでます。
データの中は
byteData　は　{byte[42]}
nowPos　　は　12
ResultByteは　{byte[29]}
strSize　　は　29
という感じでした。
色々と調べてみましたが、根本的な解決に至らずに書き込みました。
ご教授よろしくお願いします。

.net 3.5
windows 8.1

Comment: 通常その例外は`byteData.Length * sizeof(byte)` < `nowPos` + `strSize`という条件で発生しますが、42>12+29のため記載された条件であれば問題ないはずです。

Comment: 質問とは関係ないですが、`Convert.ToInt32( BytesConvert.ToHexString( Count ), 16 )`は`Count[0]`でいいと思います。

Comment: @pgrhoさんはやりそうですよね。なぜエラーが出るのかが不明で投稿させていただきました。　http://dalmore.blog7.fc2.com/blog-entry-57.html　に例えばC#でのint型は4byteなので、５要素をコピーしたい場合は4*5で20を指定する必要があります。とありますが、何か関係ありますか？

Comment: @pgrhoさんCount の件ですが、[0]だけでいいと言うのはなぜでしょうか？実はそこもエラーになり数が多いですと言われていました。

Comment: `CountSize`の変換後に`Count[0]`と比較してみてください。`BytesConvert`の実装が分からないので予想ですが、`CountSize`と同じ値が入っているのではないでしょうか。でしたら`byte`をそのまま数値として使用すればよいです。また文字の'0'-'9'が入っている可能性もありますが、この場合は48(='0')を引けばよいです。

Comment: あと仮に`COUNT_SIZE`などの数字が実際には1より大きいのであれば、エンディアンを考慮する必要があります。